# appengine datastore - relationship between property and composite indexes

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datastore

I have an Event model in my app with a "date_created" property.
I always query on Event model with an ancestoer query. Hence my composite index looks like this:

```
- kind: Event
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: date_created
    direction: desc
```

My question is - can "date_created" be unindexed (ie. "indexed=False") and the query still function properly assuming that the composite index is sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't build composite indexes using properties that are set as unindexed.

But see [issue 4231](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4231), which was "escalated to the engineering team" last week, so there's hope.